# Set UILabel font size according to its frame size?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont, pinch

I have an application that allow user to use the pinch gesture for scaling the label
How can I change the font size according to the new frame size so that the font just fit in the frame rectangle?

My current step is only set the label with new transform, and the text will look blur if the label is scaled too small/large.
I want to ensure that the label can display the text clearly where the text can have the max size according to the new frame rectangle.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

If you're using InterfaceBuilder, check "Autoshrink" for the label.

Make sure that "Minimum Size" is not too large.

Comment: Since I want to let user to pinch the size as they want, I set the font size to 300 when it init.

But the text seems not smooth when the label is small.
The code I have:
 [label setText:text];
 [label setTextColor:color];
 [label setFont:font];// font has setup to size 300
 [label setNumberOfLines:1];
 [label setMinimumFontSize:5];
 [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

Comment: Obviously there would be some limit of fonts. After some level it wont be that much smoother as they look in normal view. Otherwise i do agree with Sanjay's answer. I guess that is the only way.